# How should i use nested data in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to use data which is an array of variable length lists.  e.g., a list of cars, each car with a list of previous owners.  I was thinking of drawing something similar to a stacked horizontal bar chart.  I will draw each rectangle, rather than using a stack.

Not sure if I should use some form of nested data.

Edited after first set of responses:
I am not really looking at how to represent it visually.  In d3 from what I see the input data is always a 1 dimensional linear array.  Suppose I want to use data which is an array of lists, how do I do that.  Let's say data is like this:
[make: "Chevy", {owners: [{name:"Mike"}, {name: "Parthiban"}]},
 make: "Ford", {ownwers: [{name: "Selvi"}, {name: "John"}, {name: "Ramkrishnan"}]}]
For each make, I treat them as one data element.  However, I then want to process the data for ownwers for each make.

I don't want to use a standard layout at this point.

Note also that the data is not a clean mxn matrix.  It is an array of variable length lists.

Comment: How about a simple tree? Btw - http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/05/24/f1-championship-points-as-a-d3-js-powered-sankey-diagram/ Senkey style might also suit you.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you were thinking of? http://bl.ocks.org/3943967 I'm not sure whether the example you gave naturally translates to that representation. What are you trying to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the structure of your data, but for hierarchies you can try the [pack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout). You can have each car hold it's previous owners inside it and you can adjust their size depending on the criteria you want.

Here's [the official example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063530) and here's something [I whipped up using that](http://improve.ro/sandbox/politicians/v1.1/) ([source code here](https://github.com/cimi/infographic-politicians)).